# JQuery $.post function works in firefox but not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have a few functions on my site that update my database using $.post. These all work fine in firefox but not at all in internet explorer and i cant seem to work out why i have put the functions below:

Function 1:

```
function removeAd(ad_id) {
    $.post('remove.php', {
        id: ad_id
    }, function() {
        $('.workarea').load('display.php');
    });
};​
```

Function 2:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#addBanner').click(function() {
        $.post('add.php', {
            task: 'banner'
        }, function() {
            $('.workarea').load('display.php');
        });
    });
});​
```

Function 3:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#categoryorder").sortable({
            opacity: 0.6,
            cursor: 'move',
            update: function() {
                var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=updateRecordsListings';
                $.post("update.php", order)
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Does anyone know why these would work in Firefox but not in IE. I quite new to this and debugging isn't something I'm great at yet so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Which version of IE? *`debugging isn't something I'm great at yet`* Practice makes perfect. :)

Comment: Check the console in IE (press F12) for errors. My guess would be that the problem is something before the `$.post` which stops it from being called.

Comment: ... and which version of jQuery is involved?

Comment: press F12 to open the IE developer tools, reload the page, and the check scripts -> console area for any javascript errors.

Comment: sorry i didn't mention but i'm currently on an XP machine so i'm using IE8 and cant test IE9 i will check the console now

Comment: there was an error in my code i used console code that wasn't compatible but now i discover that it does seem to be making the changes but IE isn't refreshing properly

Comment: IE always has issues ;-) But in the future, anytime the $.post or something similar doesn't seem to be working, you have to fall back on the console and inspect every bit of your code. Learn the various consoles, they are your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE has caching issues with ajax requests.  Try using

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
```

Or adding a parameter so IE will think it's a new page and not get it from cache

```
$('.workarea').load('display.php',{getnew:new Date().getTime()});
```

Comment: i think you are right because now i can get it to make the changes but it doesn't refresh the page even if i refresh it myself. where shall i put this code?

Comment: just add it before all your code.. Or after the document.ready function

Comment: thank you so much!!
 
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false}); <--- This worked just fine